# Get results based on subset of dimensions from cloudwatch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am sending in 3 dimensions  (Clinic_Id, Email, NodeName)to CloudWatch for a Metric. While querying Cloudwatch, I want to query based on 1 dimension (Clinic_Id) and get distinct values for 3rd dimension (NodenName). Is there a workaround to achieve this? I understand Cloudwatch would consider it(one with 1 dimension) as a different metric altogether.

I came across `get_metric_data` function and I was hoping something like this should work:

```
stats = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
        MetricDataQueries=[{
            'Id': 'm1',
            'Expression': "SEARCH('{ABC/HEARTBEAT} MetricName=\"PING_PONG\"', 'Average', 300)",
            'ReturnData': True,
        },
        ],
```

Am I on the right track? if yes, what is the right syntax to achieve it. If not, what alternatives do I have?

I currently get:

```
{"Messages": [], "ResponseMetadata": {"RetryAttempts": 0, "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "RequestId": "f36c1943-0e20-460d-8757-15eedd25d0c4", "HTTPHeaders": {"x-amzn-requestid": "f36c1943-0e20-460d-8757-15eedd25d0c4", "date": "Fri, 06 Dec 2019 00:54:25 GMT", "content-length": "302", "content-type": "text/xml"}}, "MetricDataResults": []}
```

I NOW tried:

```
   MetricDataQueries=[
        {
        "Id":'m1',
        'Expression': "SEARCH('{ABC/HEARTBEAT,Client_Email, Clinic_Id, NodeName} MetricName=\"PING_PONG\" Clinic_Id = 7667', 'Average', 864000)",
        'ReturnData': True,
    },
```

In the `MetricDataResults`, I only get TimeStamps:

How do I get all values of `Clinic_Email` and `NodeName` of the records?

```
{"Messages": [], "ResponseMetadata": {"RetryAttempts": 0, "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "RequestId": "2f33cc09-61ff-40b0-9d28-72c4d949b2f0", "HTTPHeaders": {"x-amzn-requestid": "2f33cc09-61ff-40b0-9d28-72c4d949b2f0", "date": "Fri, 06 Dec 2019 22:47:25 GMT", "content-length": "928", "content-type": "text/xml"}}, "MetricDataResults": [{"Timestamps": ["2019-12-06 20:47:00+00:00"], "StatusCode": "Complete", "Values": [1.0], "Id": "m1", "Label": "simran+test2@abc.com"}, {"Timestamps": ["2019-12-06 20:47:00+00:00"], "StatusCode": "Complete", "Values": [1.0], "Id": "m1", "Label": "simran+test4@abc.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the `SEARCH` expression is the correct approach here, you just need to list all the dimensions you want to match in the curly brackets.

You matched the metric name in your example, so to get metrics with all dimensions you would do:

```
'Expression': "SEARCH('{ABC/HEARTBEAT,Clinic_Id,Email,NodeName} MetricName=\"PING_PONG\"', 'Average', 300)"
```

You say you want to match specific value of `Clinic_Id` and the metric name. You can do that with:

```
'Expression': "SEARCH('{ABC/HEARTBEAT,Clinic_Id,Email,NodeName} MetricName=\"PING_PONG\" Clinic_Id=\"SOME_VALUE\"', 'Average', 300)"
```